# How do you create a scatterplot from a .csv file with multiple columns/subsets?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a scatterplot from a .csv file which includes multiple subsets of data. I want to compare the variables and include a Key. This is an example of my dataset (the full set goes from 1900-2014).

```
Year    Race    Sex ALE
1900    Both    Both Sexes  47.3
1900    Both    Female  48.3
1900    Both    Male    46.3
1900    African American    Both Sexes  33
1900    African American    Female  33.5
1900    African American    Male    32.5
1900    Caucasian   Both Sexes  47.6
1900    Caucasian   Female  48.7
1900    Caucasian   Male    46.6
```

I have named my dataset: "life"
The graph shows up at four scatterplot lines but all in blue.

```
options(scipen = 999)
library(scales)
ggplot(data=life, aes(x=Year, y=ALE, group=1)) + 
  geom_point(colour="blue", size=.5, shape=9, fill="blue") +
  xlab("Year") + 
  ylab("Life Expectancy") + 
  ggtitle("Average Life Expectancy")
```

I want to see one scatterplot where the comparison of males, females, African Americans, Caucasians are each a line of their own in a separate color with a key. I am missing some important script that I can't figure out. Is there a way to draw a line of best fit?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following:

```
ggplot(data = lif, aes(x = Year, y = ALE)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = interaction(Race, Sex),
             size = .5, shape = 9) +
  geom_smooth() +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Life Expectancy") +
  ggtitle("Average Life Expectancy")
```

I don't have your data so I can't test this code, but I think the `aes(colour = interaction(Race, Sex))` may help.